# What's the best node module for making cURL requests?

Tags: node.js, curl, npm, request

Im looking for a node module to make a request. I see multiple different options that all seem pretty good, is there one that is considered the best, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general the request module works very well. I've done a lot with it. It's simple, elegant, powerful, and has a strong history. You can see the docs and module here: https://github.com/request/request